# How to pass variable in between cs pages?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I gathered user input in `gotoWeb.xaml.cs` and i have stored gathered input in Isolated Storage. I need to pass that stored variable to `MainPage.xmal.cs`. I dont know how to do that ?

i need this `var Page1` and `var Page2` in MainPage.xaml. How to do this ?

Code in `gotoWeb.xaml`

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Page1"] = site;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
//store it in the settings 
if (!settings.Contains("qsPage1"))
{
//if setting has not been created, add it
settings.Add("qsPage1", site);
}
else
{
//store a the page in the setting
settings["qsPage1"] = site;
}
var Page1 = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage1"];
// and by using same isolated settings method, created one more varible
var Page2 = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage2"];
```

Comment: have a look at framework like MVVM Light that might already provide you with these basic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ApplicationSettings, then the data will persist even when the app is exited. If this is what you want and if this data is also to be loadad as soon as you enter MainPage after app restart, then simply override MainPage's OnNavigatedTo to load the data from ApplicationSettings.

Answer (score 0):

You can look Messenger for MVVM Pattern.
You can pass everything and it's very easy to implement.

Answer (score -1):

Very quick and dirty:

```
page1.xml:
public class values
    {
        public static var value1 = 123;
        public static var value2 = 234;
        public static var value3 = 345;


    }

 page2.xml:

 var localvalue1 = page1.values.value1;
 var localvalue2 = page1.values.value2;
 var localvalue3 = page1.values.value3;
```